# What's the equivalent of the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission in the Netherlands?

Tags: stocks, investing, online-data-source, regulation, netherlands

I'm looking for 10-K financial statements and I can't find the SEC.gov equivalent in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Dutch equivalent of the Securities & Exchange Commission is the so-called [Autoriteit Financiële Markten](https://www.afm.nl/en). You can find the 'jaarverslagen', the Dutch equivalent of 10-K financial reports, on [this page](https://www.afm.nl/en/professionals/registers/meldingenregisters/financiele-verslaggeving).